# powershell - output rows in a .csv, based on conditions of each entry in a column

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and have had very little coding experience.

Apologies for the initial reading, I was trying to put into context what I'm attempting to do, but to make it easier, I have reduced the wall of text. and added the source files.

My sincere apologies...

I've been tasked with creating a script to verify user accounts against an output .csv from another server.
The importing .csv will have additional columns in it, but I am having trouble filtering on usernames column.
First, I output the columns I need $*'Machine Name' and $*'User Name' to "$ADUserList", removing the "" around each entry, with:

```
$SourceFile1 | select $_'Machine Name', $_'User Name' | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation | foreach { $_ -replace '^"','' -replace "`"$delimiter`"",$delimiter -replace '"$','' }|'
```

This is where I have issues:

I then import "$ADUserList" to attempt to output each row that matches the expected user format ( 8digits long, all numbers) to "GoodADUser.csv" and those that don't match to "BadADUser.csv".
 Failure point:

```
    $ADUserList = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\Output\ADUserList.csv 
ForEach-Object {$item -in $ADUserList
  IF ($SourceFile1.'User Name'.Length -eq 8 -and $SourceFile1.'User Name' -is [int])
  {$item | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter $delimiter -NoTypeInformation | foreach { $i -replace '^"','' -replace "`"$delimiter`"",$delimiter -replace '"$','' }| Out-File $PSScriptRoot\Output\GoodADUserList.csv -Force
  }
   Else 
  {$item | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter $delimiter -NoTypeInformation | foreach { $i -replace '^"','' -replace "`"$delimiter`"",$delimiter -replace '"$','' }| Out-File $PSScriptRoot\Output\BadADUserList.csv -Force
  }
}
```

At this point, I get no file output and get an error message:

```
False
ConvertTo-Csv : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Delimiter'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Drive Encryption Script\Quick Test.ps1:17 char:39
+     {$item | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter $delimiter -NoTypeInformation | foreach {  ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToCsvCommand
```

I've uploaded the script and sample files here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ajx8h3iSP9tuoAz7A37RBUvO7H5H

Thanks guys, really appreciate the help...

Comment: Did you have a question about something? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please include examples of all files involved and the desired output. Also see if its possible to make your question more concise as this is a massive wall of text.

Comment: Hi, please show us what particular points in your code do not work as you wish. Instead of explaining the general context, please be much more specific about your coding problem.

Comment: I can't `import-CSV` from your `ADUserList.csv` because it's a mangled format. It has items like `name","number` with the start and end double quotes cut off, making it not a CSV. That also appears to be what the weird importing, selecting, converting, replacing, outputting, importing does - I can't imagine what the point of that is, but mostly it generates a CSV then goes to great length to corrupt it so the rest of the script doesn't work.

Comment: General powershell comments: `$_` has no place in a `| select 'Machine Name', 'User Name'` line; You're mixing up `foreach ($item in $somearray)` and `$somearray | Foreach-Object {...}` into your error `ForEach-Object { $item -in $ADUserList` - which doesn't make sense. `-in` is also something else, it's an operator which tests for a thing being in a set. `$SourceFile1.'User Name'.Length -eq 8` is also not doing what you want, it actually tests if the file has 8 lines in it, doing the same test over and over (if the loop worked, anyway). And export /  overwriting inside a loop won't work well.

Comment: and the things you read from a text file will always be strings, especially if they have `-NoTypeInformation` so the check whether the user name `-is [int]` will always fail because it will always be a string. Also it will fail because `$sourceFile1.'User Name'` will result in an array, and an operator used on an array like that acts like a filter, and since the test will always be False, the result of the filter will be empty, and so it ends up being `-and $false`, effectively meaning the if will fail.

Comment: ok, so if I have this correct, each entry in the list is a string, so I would need a regex eg '^[\d]{8}$' to review each entry followed by output the entire line. It also looks like the export from the original file is botched to. To simplify, I could just work off the original file, but I'm not sure how I can just export the lines I want. I did initially try to just 'export-csv', but that added " to every entry

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple corrections to your script.

You probably will have better luck passing the object through a pipe to the for each method. When you do that the default object variable is $_

```
$ADUserList = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\Output\ADUserList.csv 
$ADUserList | ForEach-Object {
         $item = $_
         IF ($SourceFile1.'User Name'.Length -eq 8 -and $SourceFile1.'User Name' -is [int])
             {$item | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter $delimiter -NoTypeInformation | foreach { $i -replace '^"','' -replace "`"$delimiter`"",$delimiter -replace '"$','' }| Out-File $PSScriptRoot\Output\GoodADUserList.csv -Force
         }
         Else 
          {$item | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter $delimiter -NoTypeInformation | foreach { $i -replace '^"','' -replace "`"$delimiter`"",$delimiter -replace '"$','' }| Out-File $PSScriptRoot\Output\BadADUserList.csv -Force
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your downloaded files, this will split into "(username is 8 characters and numeric)" and "(everyone else)"

```
$users = Import-Csv machineusers.csv

$goodAccounts = @()
$badAccounts = @()

foreach ($user in $users)
{
    if (($user.'User Name'.Length -eq 8) -and 
        ([int]::TryParse($user.'User Name', [ref]$null)))
    {
        $goodAccounts += $user
    } 
    else
    {
        $badAccounts += $user
    }
}
$goodAccounts | Select 'User Name', 'Machine Name' | Export-CSV good.csv -NoTypeInformation
$badAccounts | Select 'User Name', 'Machine Name' | Export-CSV bad.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I don't know the intent of all the lines which mangle the CSV, but please don't do that, there must be a better way to achieve it.

Comment: Hi @TessellatingHeckler, that works a treat, with some minor modifications to the output path. The only issue I have with this is that when using export.csv it adds "....." to each entry, which is what I attempted to achieve in my first line and resulted in a botched format. Is there a simple way to remove """? as I need to run separate AD lookups for the user accounts...

Comment: @RobbieG1983 I don't think PowerShell built in cmdlets have any scope for different dialects of CSV. Looks like what you were doing, but replace all quotes in the line instead of just the start and end ones - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/02/remove-unwanted-quotation-marks-from-csv-files-by-using-powershell/ (that will still make the CSV corrupt if there are quotes or commas in one of the fields, but if you have to, eh).

Comment: I may have my wires crossed with the quotes "" in .csv files. Powershell add the strings and omits said quotes, as do excel when the .csv is opened. I only need to clean up the final csv if it is to be viewed in notepad, so will pass this back to the customer to find out if they need them removed.. Just goes to show how your understanding can get clouded when you have been working too long... :p